# Where do i have to put input file in eclipse(java) in order to write into it

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I am trying to enter data into a text file from a java program. The program is executing and showing the output as success but when i open the text file it is still blank. 
Here is my code

```
package com.example.ex2;


import java.io.*;  
class Input{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   try{  
     FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");  
     String s="Good MOrning";  

     byte b[]=s.getBytes();  
     fout.write(b);  

     fout.close();  

     System.out.println("success...");  
    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);}  
  }  
}
```

I think i have gone wrong in placing the text file. I have placed it in the default directory.

Comment: I tested your exact code on my machine and it worked fine. Are you checking the correct file after running the program?

Comment: can u tell me where have u placed the text file? i guess i have gone wrong there

Comment: It was placed by default in the same folder as the Java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. Check the correct file.

If you are running from IDE, it will be in the current working directory.

It is always better to your a temp or directory to store files ( certainly not in working dir)

Here is a best practice code. You can tune it further if you wish

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
            File f = new File("abc.txt");
            if (!f.isFile())
                f.createNewFile();
            fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
            String s = "Good MOrning";

            byte b[] = s.getBytes();
            fout.write(b);

            System.out.println("success... printed at : " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally
        {
            if (null != fout)
                try
                {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
        }
    }
```